# Illegal value for parameter when using ConnectApi.CommerceCart.addItemToCart

Tags: apex, connect-api, b2b-lex

I am trying to use the ConnectApi.CommerceCart for B2B Commerce to add an item to the cart in Experience Cloud. I am on the B2B Commerce Storefront template in LWR. I get this error

`Illegal value for parameter: 'effectiveAccountId'`

When I try to execute ConnectApi.CommerceCart.addItemToCart();

My code snippet is as such:

```
        try {
            
            // DEBUG
            acctID = '0035j00001ADVrpAAH';
            System.debug('AddToCart - AccountID: ' + acctID + ' webstoreId: ' + webstoreId);
            
            ConnectApi.CartItem input = ConnectApi.CommerceCart.addItemToCart(webstoreId, acctID, 'active', item);
            return input.CartId;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('exception!!! w: ' + webstoreId + ' Acc: ' + acctID);
            System.debug(e);
            throw new CustomException('Error adding item to cart! ' + e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString() + ' Account ID: ' + acctID); // debug with the message
        }
```

Based on the [Reference document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceCart_static_methods.htm), I should be able to pass in a String successfully.
Any clues why?

Comment: I'm not a CommerceCart user but  perhaps: `003...` is a SFDC Contact record; also verify CRUD and sharing permissions